# How to Record Voice in android?

Tags: android, voice, recording

I am trying to record the voice in android But it will create the .mp3 file on the path (sdcard/filename) But when i run this file it doesen't play because it doesn't record the voice.

Here is My code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case(R.id.Button01):
            try {
                //audio.start();
                startRecord();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        case(R.id.Button02):
            //audio.stop();
            stopRecord();
        }

    }
     private void startRecord() throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
           // recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  //ok so I say audio source is the microphone, is it windows/linux microphone on the emulator? 
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Music/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".amr"); 
            recorder.prepare(); 
            recorder.start();      
        }

        private void stopRecord(){
            recorder.stop();
          //recorder.release();
        }



}
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: have you checked the file size its proper or not?

Comment: it doesn't create file more than 1,0007 bytes when i try to run it, it will finish within 1 second.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Refer to the [Android Audio Capture documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) for recording audio and playing back the recorded audio.

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

public class AudioRecorder {

    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    public final String path;

    public AudioRecorder(String path) {
        this.path = sanitizePath(path);
    }

    private String sanitizePath(String path) {
        if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        if (!path.contains(".")) {
            path += ".3gp";
        }
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + path;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                    + ".");
        }

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }

    public void playarcoding(String path) throws IOException {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume(10, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you searched google, you'll find this in their API Guides:

```
/*
 * The application needs to have the permission to write to external storage
 * if the output file is written to the external storage, and also the
 * permission to record audio. These permissions must be set in the
 * application's AndroidManifest.xml file, with something like:
 *
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 *
 */
package com.android.audiorecordtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.IOException;


public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public AudioRecordTest() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[SOURCE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)

Comment: need a automatic record when mic or speaker to be used by user, but here your are using button listener,

Answer (score 0):

**Offical Example link from Google**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html#example

I suggest to only follow that one since its guaranteed to be up-to-date and secure.

Answer (score 0):

Get manifests permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

MainActivity code

```
AudioRecorder audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder("Service/Record");
    try {
        audioRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("RecordError", e.getMessage());
    }
findViewById(R.id.stopButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {
            audioRecorder.stop();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

AudioRecorder class code here:

```
public class AudioRecorder {
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
public final String path;

public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
}

private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
        path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
        path += ".mp3";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + path;
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}

public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
}

public void playarcoding(String path) throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(sanitizePath(path));
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    mp.setVolume(10, 10);
}
```

}

*** Get the user permission when the activity will start. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and RECORD_AUDIO permission.