# How to record 5 sec of sound from mic and save it as file. java.Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, voice-recording

I am trying to voice record 5 sec after a button is click. Is there a ways to do it ?
For example, when user clock on a button it starts recording 5 secs and stops. Whatever gets recorded should be saved in mp3 file. The file name is hard coded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Android Audio Capture documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) for recording audio and playing sound back.

This is possibly a duplicate of [How to Record Voice in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264687/how-to-record-voice-in-android)

Comment: Hi, it is not a duplicate although question is similar. I am mainly interested in a way to start recording for 5 sec and stop after that time. Save a file with an audio recorded. Etc. It is for my case study to check users awareness.  I tried to loop it with for loop and stop it when when I == 5 but it did not worked. I was wondering of a way to start recording for 5 sec only. Without the need to click stop button etc.

Comment: @Xarels I believe there is a Timer class or you could create your own. You simply just run the stop function after 5 seconds. The voice recording if done correctly should run until you call the stop function. In pseudo it would be startRecording(); Timer.Run(5000ms,stopRecording());

Comment: @Xarels If you want to post a minimal verifiable example I can try to assist with your specific code.

Comment: Thank you. This pretty much answers my question. I

Comment: Thanks i will do so tomorrow